# Is there a way to secure a public endpoint?

Tags: rest, security

Am I correct in thinking that a public REST api, such as a registration endpoint can't authenticate a user. For example our endpoints should only accept requests coming from our mobile applications and future web apps.

I am pretty sure it's not logically possible. I think apple and google offer a way (acting like a ca) for the server to identify a request is coming from a registered device however that changes the API to a private one. As authentication is essentially moved to the app store so only owners of app store accounts can use it.

So keeping it completely public the only way to prevent bots attacking it is to use email confirmation with auto deletion if not confirmed in x amount of time, and IP rate limiting.

A contractor suggested we use a unique secret key hard coded in to each app however, that to me sounds illogical and completely wrong. A secret between the app and server is compromised the second a user downloads the application on their device.

So am I correct about the secret key, are there any other ways to secure the endpoint from bots? The only other thing I can think of is using a captcha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 separate things here.

## Securing Public REST APIs

You are correct that a secret, even an asymmetric one, would be compromised if the attacker downloads and reverse-engineers the application. Attackers can use debuggers, Chrome developer tools, and tools like Wireshark to reverse engineer and find the secret.

In general, an attacker can mimic the behavior of the app or user, i.e. same the same requests in very similar patterns.

The approach to this in today's industry is to filter out as many of those attackers as possible using tools like [Web Application Firewalls](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-cloud-firewall), and increasingly, [Bot Management solutions](https://www.g2.com/categories/bot-detection-and-mitigation), which work for web, mobile, and APIs.

The better the tool, the more work the attacker has to do, ergo fewer are attackers willing to do it, ergo smaller chance of being attacked.

## Secure Authentication

Authentication is a specific case of the above, however this problem is currently (one of) the biggest problem faced by web applications.

The main solutions employed today is are bot filtering techniques e.g. CAPTCHA (which resourceful attackers can overcome), and Multi-Factor Authentication.

It's quite uncommon these days to be able to register without email, however services such as [10 Minute Mail](https://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html) can be used to overcome this. It's actually not very difficult to set up your own mail server as well.

Login is more difficult because you can't expect people to go through email, and even other MFA methods get quite annoying. You'd be OK with MFA for your bank account, but not with MFA to your Domino's Pizza account.

Because of that, the latest fad in web attacks is [Account Takeover](https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-account-takeover-fraud-1947476).

All those security vendors which offer WAF and bot management also try to protect APIs such as registration & login, with various degrees of success. There are even dedicated products are starting to emerge.